# Puppet applying configuration but, but doesn't do a job

Tags: linux, puppet, rhel

- Puppet v. 3.6.2 (Master and Agent)
- OS RHEL 7.2

Installed from official puppet [yum](https://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/7/products/x86_64/) repo

Puppet agent has next job results after `puppet agent -t -v`:

```
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/service_provider.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/sshfp.rb
...
...
Info: Caching catalog for ip-172-***.ec2.internal
Info: Applying configuration version '1461255100'
```

Agent conf:

```
[main]
    logdir = /var/log/puppet
    rundir = /var/run/puppet
    server = ip-172-***.ec2.internal

[agent]
    classfile = $vardir/classes.txt
    localconfig = $vardir/localconfig
    runinterval = 2h
```

Master conf:

```
[main]
    logdir = /var/log/puppet
    rundir = /var/run/puppet
    ssldir = $vardir/ssl
    ignoreimport = true
    environmentpath = $confdir/environments
    basemodulepath = $confdir/modules

[agent]
    classfile = $vardir/classes.txt
    localconfig = $vardir/localconfig
```

I even don't know where to look for, certificates are all signed and everything is fine. Can someone help me please?

Comment: What exactly is not happening?  Is there a manifest that isn't being applied?

Comment: You need to supply some more information. How are you classifying the nodes? site.pp? hiera_include? dashboard? Once you tell us how you are classifying your nodes you need to give us an example of the classification. right now it looks like you havent told puppet to apply anything.

Comment: @larsks Yes, exactly!
Thanks for your answers guys, but after a couple of days of Puppet headache the question is no longer relevant. I choose Ansible, and it works great)